# Calculation of second moment of stopping time of a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

I want to calculate second moment of stopping time of random walk (Starting from $k (0 < k < N))$ with absorbing ends at 0 and N. 
$P(X_i = 1) = p, P(X_i = -1) = q$ and
$p+q = 1$. 
$S_n - k = \sum_{1}^{n} X_i$ 
Stopping time T = min$(T_0,T_N)$. 
I am using martingale $(S_n - k - (p-q)n)^2 - 4pqn$.
$E[(S_T - k)^2]+(p-q)^2 E[T^2]-2(p-q)E[(S_T - k)T]-4pq E[T]=0$ by Optional stopping theorem. 
How to calculate $E[(S_T - k)T]$ ?

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $p$ and $q$? Typically the reasoning for the symmetric random walk ($p=q=1/2$) is different from the reasoning for the asymmetric random walk ($p \neq q$)

Comment: p $\neq$ q. Otherwise the the cross term I asked will be zero.

Comment: It is enough to find second moments of $T_0$ and $T_N$ separately if that is possible.